# Twitch get videos for a user

Tags: video, twitch

For an application, I need to get a list of videos/streams posted by a user.
I have read through the twitch.tv API (https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API) but I am unable to find anything.
All I can find is how to obtain a list of videos/streams that a user has subscribed to.

Can someone please help me to obtain the list of videos posted by a user?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are talking about twitch highlights or past broadcasts. If you are looking for highlights, you can get those from:

```
https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/USERNAME/videos?limit=10
```

The limit can be changed to get as many as you need. The results are returned as a JSON and look like this:

```
{
"_total": 179,
"videos": [
{
  "title": "Twitch Weekly - February 6, 2015",
  "description": "Twitch Weekly LIVE on February 6, 2015!",
  "broadcast_id": 13019796368,
  "status": "recorded",
  "tag_list": "",
  "_id": "c6055863",
  "recorded_at": "2015-02-06T21:01:09Z",
  "game": null,
  "length": 4015,
  "preview": "http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv.thumbs/archive-621292653-320x240.jpg",
  "url": "http://www.twitch.tv/twitch/c/6055863",
  "views": 318,
  "broadcast_type": "highlight",
  "_links": {
    "self": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/videos/c6055863",
    "channel": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/twitch"
  },
  "channel": {
    "name": "twitch",
    "display_name": "Twitch"
  }
},
...
],
"_links": {
"self": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/twitch/videos?limit=10&offset=0",
"next": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/twitch/videos?limit=10&offset=10"
}
}
```

If your would like the past broadcasts for a video, you can get those from:

```
https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/USERNAME/videos?broadcasts=true
```

They are also returned as a JSON and look similar to this:

```
"videos": [
{
"title": "BlizzCon Pre-Show Powered by T-Mobile",
"description": null,
"broadcast_id": 17504505664,
"status": "recorded",
"tag_list": "",
"_id": "v24147264",
"recorded_at": "2015-11-05T20:10:56Z",
"game": "Gaming Talk Shows",
"length": 4276,
"delete_at": null,
"is_muted": false,
"preview": "http://static cdn.jtvnw.net/v1/AUTH_system/vods_6d3c/twitch_17504505664_342107744/thumb/thumb0-320x240.jpg",
"url": "http://www.twitch.tv/twitch/v/24147264",
"views": 150,
"fps": {
"audio_only": 0,
"medium": 30.0000584614125,
"mobile": 19.9816431164609,
"high": 30.0000584614125,
"low": 30.0000584614125,
"chunked": 59.9998830771748
},
"resolutions": {
"medium": "852x480",
"mobile": "400x226",
"high": "1280x720",
"low": "640x360",
"chunked": "1280x720"
},
"broadcast_type": "archive",
"created_at": "2015-11-05T20:11:19Z",
"_links": {
"self": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/videos/v24147264",
"channel": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/twitch"
},
"channel": {
"name": "twitch",
"display_name": "Twitch"
}
}
```

Comment: Yes, this works.
I was confused, but figured out that channel and user are essentially the same.